# Jquery targeting more than one of something

Tags: jquery

i need to remove the image inside the link. Then I need to move the first image into the link for each of the row divs. Here is the fiddle. my current code (commented out) moves all of the first images into all of the links.

http://jsfiddle.net/1hxhdfpb/1/

```
$( ".field-link a img").hide();
$( ".field-image img" ).appendTo( ".field-link a");
```

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want, but I'm not sure if you wanted the 'people' image removed entirely, or if you wanted the 'cat image' cloned, instead of moved, so I moved it:

```
$('.field-link a img').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.replaceWith(self.closest('.field-link').prev('.field-image').find('img'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1hxhdfpb/2/).

Or, if you'd prefer to clone the 'cat image', rather than move it:

```
$('.field-link a img').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.replaceWith(self.closest('.field-link').prev('.field-image').find('img').clone());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1hxhdfpb/4/).

To *hide* the 'people image,' instead of removing it, and copy the 'cat image' after it:

```
$('.field-link a img').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.hide().after(self.closest('.field-link').prev('.field-image').find('img').clone());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1hxhdfpb/5/).

References:

- [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Comment: The first one is exactly what i asked for, thank you. The others are very useful and taught me a few things. Great fiddles!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/1hxhdfpb/3/

```
$('.field-link').each(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   $(self.find('a img')).remove();
   $(self.find('img')).appendTo($(self.find('a')));

});
```

That works, although quite hacky. If I understand you correctly, you want to **remove** the person image. In this case, `hide` is not the right method, as it just makes it invisible.